# How do I add multiple Web pages on my news website and maintain them professionally

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, crud

I have been coding a news website and have coded the homepage of it by HTML and CSS. I added some buttons on the nav-bar like about,contact etc. I know that to make these buttons working I have to link another HTML page under the href function of the HTML file of Homepage. I did that and it worked too but now I don't understand that how will I link each and every news article displayed on the homepage. Also there will be hundreds of articles I want to put up on the website in future. Then do I need to make hundreds of different HTML pages too ? In simple words Can you please explain how can I add multiple article web-pages on my website without making a mess of files on the IDE ? And also explain that how these websites like Amazon , the verge , Huffpost etc or even stack overflow and Quora have so many products or articles? How do they do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so there are different ways you can do that. You **don't have to create multiple web pages everyday and maintain them separately**. Big websites use **CRUD(create, read, update, delete) systems** for handling big amounts of data on their web applications.

For example we can use Django-Templating for handling multiple articles on your news website, where you will create one base file and for every article you will extend it from the base file and not have to create a separate file for every news article. You will also be able to create new articles on the website without coding every specific article as it will become a CRUD system. Only HTML and CSS is not sufficient to create CRUD systems.

Some programming languages and frameworks that can help you create a crud system are:

1. Java - Hibernate, iBatis, JOOQ
2. PHP - Laravel Eloquent ORM, Propel , Doctrine
3. .NET - Entity Framework, nHibernate, LLBLGen Pro
4. Python - Django, Flask
5. Ruby- Ruby on Rails

These are just some top frameworks but there are numerous languages and frameworks you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you mean. why are you creating a file for new news? You can use database for other and new news. This way it becomes news.php and you can show it by every news id.I do not be able to understand exactly what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is a Content Management System or CMS. It's basically a collection of templates(forms) that allow us to create content quickly and uniformly.  So you would code a form that collects user input like 'URL', 'Title', 'Body', 'Image', 'Author', 'Date', etc. and posts the input to a database on a server. Then when your readers make a page request, that page would then be created dynamically. So you never actually 'code' separate pages. You code the templates for pages like 'Homepage', News Article, Sport Article, Entertainment Article, classified listing, etc.

You would code one News Article template, but you could have thousands of articles on your site.

You have a choice to build your own CMS or use an existing one. I would check out a few of the available options out there.

https://www.drupal.org/

https://wordpress.com/

https://www.djangoproject.com/

They all have free options that will shave countless hours off development time on your News website.